# Interesting bug? in OSX preinstalled Ruby (1.8.7)

Tags: ruby

```
2**2
=> 4

2**63
=> -9223372036854775808

2**63 + 2**63
=> -18446744073709551616
```

`64` and everything after it returns `0`

```
2**64
=> 0

2**65
=> 0

2**100
=> 0

2**1000
=> 0
```

Same version works just well on Linux.

Any clues?

Running OSX 10.8.2 in 64bit mode.

No RVM/Rbenv.

Ruby 1.9.3 works just well.

Comment: Looks like an integer overflow.

Comment: Interesting one. Could you please add the result of executing `2**63 + 2**63` The bug can not reproduce on my environment so I can not try it for myself.

Comment: Wow! This is really stunnig! Even integer overflow can not explain how do you get a result that is `-2^64` when addign 2^63 to 2^63 Unless you have a 65 bit integer it does not make any sense to me :? It seems arithmetics with big integers is totatlly broken on your system. How about bigger expressions? Can you calculate 2^123?

Comment: @izomorphius, not sure about the system, 1.9.3 works correctly. question updated

Comment: I can reproduce this on "ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]" (from `ruby -v`) and "irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)" (from `irb -v`).

Comment: Idem with Ruby 1.8.7 shipped with Mountain Lion, but not with 1.8.6 or 1.9.2 I have installed with RVM.

Comment: Some possibly related links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009799/exponentiation-in-ruby-1-8-7-returns-wrong-answers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130557/large-multiplication-output-coming-out-negative-in-ruby and https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/4e4649e13cd4175aab75a0edc2fc5b082cf735d1.

Comment: Another expression -2**63 ... with port-installed ruby 1.8.7 `$ /opt/local/bin/ruby1.8 -e 'p -2**63'` yields
`-9223372036854775808`

with preinstalled ruby on MacOs 10.8.3: `$ ruby -e 'p -2**63'` yields
9223372036854775808

Comment: I've confirmed this issue with the system ruby in ML, but it is not an issue with ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i686-darwin12.2.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/4e4649e13cd4175aab75a0edc2fc5b082cf735d1) on Ruby implementation that has been fixed by patch 358.

It was cause by the fact that the returned value of the multiplication was declared [`volatile`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#C.2B.2B11) which means that *couldn't be optimized*. 
The default C optimization wouldn't have caused the [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow), therefore the `volatile` keyword was removed.

On Ruby 1.9.3 works [correctly](http://ideone.com/SQupWI).