# Different exponent behavior for different ruby versions

Tags: ruby, math, exponent, ruby-1.8.7

I'm trying to calculate `2^1000` in ruby, but I'm getting different results for different versions. Any idea why?

Using 1.8.7:

```
~ » rbenv global system                                                                         ~  
~ » ruby --version                                                                              ~  
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
~ » irb                                                                                         ~  
>> 2 ** 1000
0
>> exit
```

Using ruby 1.9.3

```
~ » rbenv global 1.9.3-p194                                                                     ~  
~ » ruby --version                                                                              ~  
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.1.0]
~ » irb                                                                                         ~  
>> 2 ** 1000
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
>> exit
```

I can get around using that syntax and have it work, but I'm just curious why it results in 0 in 1.8.7.

Comment: With `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i686-darwin12.2.0]` on my machine, the value is correct.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your odd 1.8.7 behavior.  Running under rvm, and using 1.8.7-p358, I get the same results as 1.9.3-p125.

Comment: It might be a bug in that version of 1.8.7, the same thing happens on my Mac using the system ruby. Maybe it's related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009799/exponentiation-in-ruby-1-8-7-returns-wrong-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reasonaly certain that you are experiencing [the bug mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009799/exponentiation-in-ruby-1-8-7-returns-wrong-answers).

It appears as though it was [fixed by this commit to Ruby trunk](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/4e4649e13cd4175aab75a0edc2fc5b082cf735d1), which made it to Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and greater.